# Swift: Show different views based on condition

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app that displays changing tasks for the user (the plan is to show one task per day, at the moment it simply displays a random task on load).

Flow: The user logs into the app and is directed to the home screen where the daily task is displayed.
Once he completed the task, he clicks a "Mark completed" button and a success screen is presented modally.
When the user closes the success screen, he returns to the home screen, where currently the daily task is still displayed.

**I want to change the view on the home screen, so that when coming back from the success screen, the user will see a different view instead of showing the task that was displayed previously (i.e. a message saying "You completed the daily task").**

A new task should only be displayed on the next day (or any other condition).

The logic is:

If dailyActivityCompleted = false > show daily activity view

If dailyActivityCompleted = true > show "completed" view

**What's the best way to conditionally determine which content to display within the same UIViewController?**

I am new to Swift so sorry if this is a basic question, I searched but couldn't find the way to do it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to conditionally determine which content to display within the same UIViewController?

The best way is to maintain a data model that manages the state of the app, including the list of tasks, current task, completion status, etc. Once you have that, the view controller's job is to ensure that its view reflects the model, or at least the part of the model that it displays. Anytime something happens that could change the model's state, you can have the view controller check the model and update itself. For example, if you use a segue to display the success view controller, you can implement `unwindFromSegue(segue:)` to call some method that checks the model and updates the view.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to do some research on that :) 

I'm assuming I don't have to actually store all the data within the data model? (I'm working with Firebase and would like to get the data from there)

Comment: If I said "your car should have an engine" and you said "I was hoping to use Toyota products," there'd be some overlap there, right? Firebase is a platform for building mobile apps, including data storage, but also other things like analytics and testing. You should read about the "model-view-controller" or "MVC" pattern (and esp. the way iOS uses it). Your app should have a model; if you want to build that model using Firebase-brand parts, that's fine.